# Alt+Fx change to console x instead of triggering special functions (Debian + Cinnamon)

Tags: debian, cinnamon

After a recent upgrade (Debian sid + Cinnamon) the Keycombination <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd> changes to console x, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> brings up `tty4` instead of triggering the function attached to this combination, in this case close the active window.

Changing back to the Desktop (tty7), the special function attached to the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd> keys I pressed (which brought me to `ttyx`) is executed.

Changing to console x is still also possible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd>, which was how I changed consoles before.

Example:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> => changes to `tty4`
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> => changes to `tty7` (=Desktop) *and* executes the action attached to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> (in my case: close the active window)

I noticed that the package `console-setup` was upgraded, but there were no alerts regarding the configuration file. I reconfigured the package with `dpkg-reconfigure`, but there is no option regarding the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd> keys.

[A somewhat similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34460/disabling-or-changing-console-switching-keys) was related to the keyboard layout, but but since I did not change the keyboard configuration I suspect that the new behaviour is related to something else.

On which levels of the stack is this behaviour defined (console, X, Cinnamon)?

How can I revert to the previous behaviour (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd> not changing console but just execute special function)?

Comment: It is sid. Just wait or (better) check and fill a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is not precise by any standards, but still: The system changed back to normal behaviour after a reboot. I did not change any configuration files related to the problem and I can't reproduce the issue.